# How to build out-of-tree Fuchsia OS program

Tags: gn, fuchsia

After installing and building Fuchsia OS, I can modify the string in the example hello world program from "Hello, World!\n" to "Hello, Fuchsia!\n".
Then I [build](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/development/build/fx) and execute the code which produces the expected string "Hello, Fuchsia!" using:

```
cd fuchsia
fx set bringup.x64 --with //examples/hello_world
fx build; fx qemu
hello_world_cpp
```

This is fine for understanding how to change part of the Fuchsia "distribution". How do I create my own program outside of the fuchsia tree? I assume one would do normally this when creating program for running on Fuchsia OS so that one can manage the source cleanly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

The `third_party` directory is meant for modules that are managed outside of the Fuchsia tree. In the top-level `.gitignore` the directory is excluded ([link](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/fuchsia/+/ca25b23c7026fda7511073f0c5278e2cfde5cdf3/.gitignore#76)):

```
/third_party/*
```

You can see that this folder is mostly empty in git ([link](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/fuchsia/+/ca25b23c7026fda7511073f0c5278e2cfde5cdf3/third_party/)). It is first populated during bootstrap ([link](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/development/source_code)), which internally uses `jiri update` to fetch repos specified in the integration manifest (e.g. for [`third_party`](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/integration/+/e52272be6dbfcb3061a57b19b034c89de1dbd321/third_party/flower)).

You would maintain your module in a separate `git` repo. For development, you would clone this repo into a sub-directory in `third-party`. Because of the `.gitignore` entry, it will not be tracked by the Fuchsia `git`.

### Example

Files:

```
third_party/hello_world/BUILD.gn
third_party/hello_world/hello_world.cc
```

`BUILD.gn`:

```
import("//build/package.gni")

group("hello_world") {
  deps = [ ":hello-world-cpp" ]
}

executable("bin") {
  output_name = "my_hello_world_cpp"
  sources = [ "hello_world.cc" ]
}

package("hello-world-cpp") {
  deps = [ ":bin" ]
  binaries = [
    {
      name = "my_hello_world_cpp"
    },
  ]
}
```

`hello_world.cc`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::cout << "Hello, World (out-of-tree)!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Build and run:

```
$ fx set bringup.x64 --with //third_party/hello_world
$ fx build
$ fx qemu
$ my_hello_world_cpp
Hello, World (out-of-tree)!
```